# PPS: how to adjust system clock from PPS?

Tags: linux, timer, ntp, real-time-clock, system-clock

In Linux PPS documentation it is said:

> PPS means "pulse per second" and a PPS source is just a device which
>   provides a high precision signal each second so that an application
>   can use it to adjust system clock time.

But I haven't find out how to do this adjusting of system clock timer (hwclock).
I rather not use ntp, just in the simplest way, to have the system timer synchronized with PPS.

**Is that possible to adjust system timer from PPS (without using ntp) ?**

I also don't fully understand the pps time ,as can be read from userspace using `time_pps_fetch` command (see ppstest.c example)

**How is it that linuxpps provides nanosecond resolution if it is a clock which is only "pulse per second" ?**

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need and a pps device (like /dev/pps0) inside your system.

You can make it through **ldattach**  command like '*sudo ldattach pps /dev/ttyS0*', if you already have PPS source (like gps receiver) connected to the serial port (/dev/ttyS0). After that you can feed /dev/pps0 to time_pps_fetch function as a device path. Or to console application **pps_test**. You can read more detailed description (with udev's rules, autostart through systemd service) [here](https://www.crc.id.au/2016/09/24/adding-a-pps-source-to-ntpd/).

I hope it will help you ;)

Comment: The approach allows you to know when the second was triggered (to the next second). Adjusting itself has to be made through adjtime() function (see man 2 adjtime) if mircoseconds resolution is enough for you. Or through adjtimex (see man 8 adjtimex and man 2 adjtimex) if you need nanoseconds adjusting and ability to change you system time's frequency. For long syncrhonized work without PPS signals.

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to sync system timer with pps without ntpd. Isn't it possible?

Comment: I mean isn't there any simple wayvto attach system timer with pps? The above description is complex and use ntpd

Comment: I don't now a way simpler than feeding PPS source to ntpd, I'm afraid. If you don't want to write your own solution (via adtimex()).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use ntpd when required to attach the system clock to PPS.

Any other alternatives requires writing implementation using adjtimex().